# jQuery: Store additional/extra data/info inside a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible and smart to store extra data inside a jQuery object?

Right now I have objects that contain some data but these objects also have a visual representation of that data. This works but I have a lot of code to keep them both in sync.

For example if you delete an object from the dom I also have to delete the related object from the object array. Deleting is fairly simple but it gets a little more complicated if I start sorting/moving the objects around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for this :)

For example:

```
$.data(element, 'varName', value);      //store
var value = $.data(element, 'varName'); //get
```

Or use the object method [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$("#ElementID").data('varName', value);      //store
var value = $("#ElementID").data('varName'); //get
```

This doesn't store the data *on* the object, rather it stores it in `$.cache` (try it in your console on this page), but it's associated with the object, via `this[$.expando]`.

However if you call [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) that removes an object, or [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), it'll do the cleanup for you.  You can also call [`.removeData()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) or [`$.removeData()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/) to remove it directly.

Comment: @Pickels - Welcome :) I added a few more methods at the end you may be interested in, since you're managing the objects directly (at least that's my take from the question).

Comment: I thought I read about cache before so that got me wondering in the first place if it was possible to store related data. Thanks for the extra methods this will make my code a lot less complex.