# How do I store extra data together with Tag-it tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

We are using [Tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/) with an Ajax call as a `tagSource` for tagging content. We need to include more data than the tag label itself, e.g. an id different than the label or metadata such as type of tag. Data that is returned to the Ajax call but we wouldn't like to include in the tag label itself.

We could modify Tag-it to include data with `li` items using [jQuery's `.data` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292441/jquery-store-additional-extra-data-info-inside-a-jquery-object) but if someone else already have solved this or can recommend another tag library it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The key to doing this without modifying Tag-it is to bridge the gap between the extra data that is returned from the autocomplete Ajax call and the Tag-it afterTagAdded event.

Add a variable `itemData` to a scope, which will be used to store the additional data from the autocomplete item:

```
{
    var itemData;
```

Get a reference to the tags element so that the create tag behavior can be called

```
    var theTags = $('#tags');

    theTags.tagit({
```

Handle the `select` event of the autocomplete and store the additional data from the selected autocomplete item, then create the tag.

```
        autocomplete: {
            source: [
                {value:'User Tag',data:{id: 1, type: 'userTag'}},
                {value:'System Tag',data:{id: 2, type: 'systemTag'}}
            ],
            select: function(event,ui) {
                itemData = ui.item.data;
                theTags.tagit("createTag", ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        },
```

Handle the `afterTagAdded` event for Tag-it. In here any custom behavior to modify the just added tag can be implemented.

```
        afterTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
            if (itemData) {
                $(ui.tag).data('type', itemData); // store all data
                $(ui.tag).find('input').val(itemData.id); // use a bit of the data
                itemData = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

See a working example of this solution at http://jsfiddle.net/yuhxL/2/